# Aggregate audio device can't record voice call

Tags: macos, audio, headphones, recording, midi

I have used [Blackhole](https://github.com/ExistentialAudio/BlackHole) on a Mac for a while. Typically I use headphones (wired ones or wireless AirPods) during a Zoom meeting or a voice call (like WeChat).

In the Zoom case, I can easily record everything (what I hear from others and my own voice) with any headphones. I just create an aggregate audio device from Blackhole 2ch and the headphone's microphone and select it as the sound input in Mac's Midi setup. It then works well in both [Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/) and QuickTimePlayer.

But in the voice call case, the same cannot record what I hear from others at all. What could be missing here?